# Monitor "WHO" altered registry key

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I need to monitor a specific registry key in HKCU for changes. Most importantly I need to know when it changed, who changed it (the process) and what it changed too.

I know this can be done via Proc Mon, however the complications of the situation means I can't go installing new external software onto a machine I need to monitor. 
Also the command line use of this program isn't suitable for my needs.

I can however implement a VBS or small c# / VB application, so long as it runs silently.

Is there a simple way to monitoring a key and if it changes record the change? Again, most important thing here is which process changed it.

Any thoughts on how this can be done appreciated.

Comment: If you can't install software why can you run a VB script?

Comment: It's a customers network and customers build of machines. It'll be easier to persuade them to run something lightweight.

Comment: Why is the Process Monitor command-line insufficient? And what's wrong with Process Monitor (which is portable, http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe) that makes it worse than your own script or executable?

Comment: @TomWijsman because the environment it must work in will not allow pop-ups or questions to the user. This cannot happen. Even with /quiet /minimized etc... set, ProcMon still asks questions on load following a reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MS Windows built in auditing to monitor changes via the Security event logs.

Enable "Audit Object Access" via either the group or local security policy. Security Settings/Local Policy/Audit Policy/Audit object access (Success, Failure).

Open the Registry and adjust the Permissions on HKCU (or the specific subkey). Permissions/Advanced/Auditing. Add the Everyone user and select the Access types you want to monitor.

All registry add, remove, edit, etc will be logged in the Security event log. Filter as needed.